# Helpers in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, helper

I make an application writed in Rails, it's growing fast and I learning with it. But I'm don't understand about helpers.

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
    # This file it's empty
end
```

users_helper.rb

```
module UsersHelper

    def avatar
        # Do something
    end
end
```

customer_helper.rb

```
module CustomerHelper
    # This file it's empty
end
```

Why in any customer's view can call avatar helper method on user helper module?
Then, why separate helpers in many files?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: Rails' version 4.

Comment: Are you sure your users_helper is defined like this: `module ApplicationHelper`? if it does, then you have defined avatar method within the `ApplicationHelper` module and that's why it works.

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake writing example.

Comment: I assume you wrote the question wrong? and users_helper has: `UsersHelper`, right?

Comment: Splitting your helpers into different files will make your code cleaner. You might not notice when there are three empty files, but your app might grow, and then you'll be grateful for some structure instead of one big file. By default, every view has access to any helpers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because all helpers are included in all controllers, by default. The separate files are really just for logical separation in this scenario. You can change that behaviour though:

> By default, each controller will include all helpers.
>
> In previous versions of Rails the controller will include a helper
>   whose name matches that of the controller, e.g., MyController will
>   automatically include MyHelper. To return old behavior set
>   `config.action_controller.include_all_helpers` to `false`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html

Comment: Is there a particular reason why they've moved to including all helpers by default? Seems unnecessary. Is there a negative effect on performance for including all as opposed to only including helpers you need in each controller?

Answer (score 0):

To add to Mike Campbell's answer:

---

**Framework**

> As magic as it is, Rails is a set of files which are called
>   sequentially
>
> These files hold `classes`, `methods`, etc; but they're still files.
>   And that means that when you run an action through Rails, it loads up
>   a series of other [`dependent`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_%28computer_science%29) files to help it run (that's what a
>   framework is)
>
> The design of Rails is such that your `helper` methods are *all*
>   loaded each time you run an action. I don't know why, but it helps
>   administer the methods for different areas of your app

So to answer your question, there's no real reason why the helpers are split up, at least with Rails 4